# How do I buy land in Falkreath?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm having trouble trying to buy land in Falkreath.  I am level 30 and I am the Thane of Falkreath, yet when I try to buy the land from the steward, it will not give me the option of buying land.

I am playing the legendary edition on Xbox 360.

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug once(Also xbox 360) I was like level 80 something and then I got legendary which gave me the DLCs and I was never able to buy land in Falkreath, from my experience I don't think there is a way to fix this as you're suppose to to get a letter from the Jarl speaking of opportunities to buy a house from a courier. If this character was made before you got the DLCs you might not be able to get the house, I could be wrong .. I couldn't find anything about it on the wiki to find a solution and I had to make a new character.

Resources:
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Lakeview_Manor